# Are your Guild Wars account keys tied to your E-Mail?

Tags: guild-wars

I owned Guild Wars and Guild Wars Factions back in the day, but I cannot for the life of me find either of the disks or CD-Keys.

Are the keys tied to my E-mail account? So if I download the free trial and login with my E-mail will my keys be attached?

Or am I totally screwed if I cannot find my keys?

Comment: I've removed your second question. It's completely unrelated to your first question, so you should [ask](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a separate question.

Comment: I guess in my head they were related becasue caring if my CDkey can be recovered hinged upon reserving my name haha. Maybe I'll still start it up though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need your CD Keys memorized. These keys are indeed attached to your email. The email doesn't even need to be active anymore. I have on several occasions had to uninstall Guild Wars in the past to "focus" on school work. Each time I reinstalled, I just enter my email and password(now you also need to enter the name of one of your characters) and logged in successfully without entering my CD Keys.

I have also on several occasions stayed over at a friends house who also played Guildwars. I was able to just log on using my email/password without having to deal with the CD Keys at all.

Comment: I've edited out your answer to the askers second question, which I already removed (see my comment above).

Comment: @Wipqozn Ah okay thanks. You must have edited it while I was typing my answer so I didn't see it.